# How to communicate with the cloud using a Raspberry Pi connected to internet using GSM module sim900?

Tags: internet, gsm

I am working on a project, in which I need to receive sensor data from remote sensors to internet cloud and sending control signals from cloud to controller.

I am using GSM sim900 to access internet for the Raspberry Pi and want to send data to IoT cloud and from the control room send data to the cloud which is then sent to the Raspberry Pi.

In short, I need two-way communication between the Raspberry Pi and cloud servers.

Comment: This question might get more attention and better answers on iot.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Use the 
Python 3 classes for SIM 900 GSM module

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from test_shared import *
from lib.sim900.inetgsm import SimInetGSM

COMPORT_NAME            = "com22"

#logging levels
CONSOLE_LOGGER_LEVEL    = logging.INFO
LOGGER_LEVEL            = logging.INFO

def main():
    """
    Tests HTTP GET and POST requests.

    :return: true if everything was OK, otherwise returns false
    """

    #adding & initializing port object
    port = initializeUartPort(portName=COMPORT_NAME)

    #initializing logger
    (formatter, logger, consoleLogger,) = initializeLogs(LOGGER_LEVEL, CONSOLE_LOGGER_LEVEL)

    #making base operations
    d = baseOperations(port, logger)
    if d is None:
        return False

    (gsm, imei) = d

    inet = SimInetGSM(port, logger)

    logger.info("attaching GPRS")
    if not inet.attachGPRS("internet", "", "", 1):
        logger.error("error attaching GPRS")
        return False

    logger.info("ip = {0}".format(inet.ip))

    #making HTTP GET request
    logger.info("making HTTP GET request")

    if not inet.httpGet(
            "httpbin.org",
            80,
            "/get?action=data_echo&data=ABC_DATA&foo=bar&ip={0}".format(inet.ip),
            1
    ):
        logger.error("error making HTTP GET request: {0}".format(inet.errorText))
        return False

    logger.info("httpResult = {0}".format(inet.httpResult))
    if inet.httpResponse is not None:
        response = str(inet.httpResponse).replace("\n\r", "\n")
        logger.info("response: \"{0}\"".format(response))
    else:
        logger.info("empty response")

    #making 3 http post requests
    for i in range(3):
        logger.info("making HTTP POST request #{0}".format(i))
        if not inet.httpPOST(
                "httpbin.org",
                80,
                "/post",
                "action=change&ip={0}&iteration={1}".format(inet.ip, i+1)
        ):
            print("[FAILED]")
            return False

        logger.info("httpResult = {0}".format(inet.httpResult))
        if inet.httpResponse is not None:
            response = str(inet.httpResponse).replace("\n\r", "\n")
            logger.info("response: \"{0}\"".format(response))
        else:
            logger.info("empty response")


    logger.debug("detaching GPRS")
    if not inet.dettachGPRS():
        logger.error("error detaching GRPS: {0}".format(inet.errorText))
        return False

    gsm.closePort()
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    print("DONE")
```

Source: https://github.com/JFF-Bohdan/sim-module